# Python Windows Service - Respond to PC Shutdown

Tags: python, windows, service, sqlalchemy, shutdown

I have a working windows service, coded in python. The service uses `SQLAlchemy` to connect to a database, and send PC statisticts back to the DB to be later displayed on an internal Web Page.

The service in its working version, uses no implementation of `SvcShutdown` . When trying to add an implementation of `SvcShutdown` None of the code is being executed. And I am obviously not getting my database update.

The only update that needs to occur is to update a database value from `True` to `False` . This value represents the PC online.

Placing the logic into the `SvcStop` Does not work either. On Shutdown the service will stop, but the update will not be received.

Is this is a fools' errand? Will the service ever be able to report its own online/offline state?

In the code below `EditSession` is custom session wrapper and `EditSTation` is a custom object to be used with the session

### Current Code

```
# Overridden Windows Service
class EditService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    """ Windows Service Class Implementation. Edit Service runs on a pulse,
    writes BgInfo files locally, and reports back to  db  """

    _svc_name_ = serviceName
    _svc_display_name_ = serviceDisplayName
    _svc_description_ = serviceDescription

    def __init__(self, args):
        """ Init the Service Framework, and create placeholder Event for Stopping"""
        self.timeout = 3000
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcShutdown(self):
        """
        Handle PC Shutdown
        :return:
        """
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Shutdown Called")
        my_session = session.EditSession(bind=engine)
        my_session.set_offline(EditStation())
        my_session.commit()
        my_session.close()
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Done Shutdown")
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcStop(self):
        """ Handle Stop signal - Report The Service Status to OS, and set the event to the stop holder"""

        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        """ Handle Start Signal - """

        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        retry_counter = 0
        while True:
            # Wait for service stop signal, if I timeout, loop again
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)

            # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # Stop signal encountered
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("EditService - STOPPED")
                if "my_session" in locals():
                    my_session.rollback()
                    my_session.close()
                break
            else:
                try:
                    # Do Work and Sleep at end
                if win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, sleepTime) == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("EditService - STOPPED")
                    break


def ctrl_handler(*args):
    servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Handler: {0}".format(args))
    print(args)
    import time
    time.sleep(10)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrl_handler, True)
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(EditService)
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: [serviceEvents.py](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/file/835a071ad7bf/win32/Demos/service/serviceEvents.py) shows how to handle additional control events. For Vista+ maybe try [`SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996) (not for XP/2003).

Comment: @eryksun it handles sessions opened in the `# Do Work and Sleep at end`   I will look into your suggestion closer after the Holiday. Vista not required. Windows XP only for now. thanks for the response

Comment: `SvcShutdown` should be called, so I'd think you'd at least see the log messages. I don't know whether or not you can talk to the database at this stage. I suggested the pre-shutdown notification on account of this, but that's not available in XP.

Comment: The Log messages do not print in event viewer, I am not able to really dig into it today. Thanks for the tips, Happy thanksgiving @eryksun

Comment: `win32service.SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT` is probably what Ill try first

Comment: @eryksun so it seems within my initial testing that implementing `control == win32service.SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE:` and `control == win32service.SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN:` are both triggered upon Shutdown. The Shutdown method does not actually work for me at all, no logging, event viewer or anything. And I am in fact using `PRESHUTDOWN` to successfully get db updates! I will continue testing but this is extremely promising. Thanks Eryk

Comment: Just a note for edification, that this does add some time to the shutdown process. It will display a screen "Shutting down xxx Service" and take even more time than required to process such a small amount of code